# CSS rendering issue on Chrome

Tags: css

I have been searching online but could not find an answer. Basically, I have a CSS file but the font color couldn't render when the page was first loaded. This only occur in Chrome. The font color would only be back after I press inspect or check or uncheck any one of the properties. How could I go about resolving this issue. I have added a versioning to the back of the CSS such that would not store cache. I am doing this on asp.net that host on sharepoint server. Greatly appreciate if anyone could give me a clue. I cannot post anything due to confidential matter.

Comment: we understand the confidential matter, but If you cannot post your code, then you, probably, cannot be helped

Comment: What code do i need to show. Because it's all the CSS font color that could not be render.

Comment: You need to show your code, it may have specific problems. That `font color` attribute that you refers, we don't know how you codded it, we need your code to be able to help you in your specific problem